# NCurses library with widgets

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm looking for a pure-C library on top of Ncurses that offers a set of pre-made widgets (especially and most important, a table widget).
I'm aware of CDK, which offers quite some widgets, but it doesn't offer the one that I most need. Is there any other library that will offer me this specific functionality?

EDIT: Please see my comment

Comment: While this could fit as "off-topic", it certainly has value for the community. The question got 4 upvotes and not a single comment, I'm pretty sure there is no risk of spam. Can you please reopen then question?

Comment: http://invisible-island.net/cdk/

Comment: @JoeBeuckman did you read my question?

Comment: Did you mention CDK before? I am just getting into CDK so I wanted you to see it.

Comment: @JoeBeuckman in my question, I clearly state that I'm aware of CDK and that it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think that there are at C. Excluding NCurses requirement, on python there are: urwid, python-prompt-toolkit and textual. They have many stars on github, recent builds on major Linux distributions. What is that having to do with C? Python has a well documented C API. You have to make some macros to call/add functions, increment/decrement references, but it is a good solution.